# Access imported contract's function on behalf of another contract using delegatecall

Tags: solidity, foundry, delegatecall, abiencoderv2

So I have two contracts. the firt one is a contract that imports a token

```
import {testToken} from "./testToken.sol";
testToken public token;
```

and has this functionality

```
AddressUpgradeable.functionDelegateCall(
                address(this),
                data[i]
            );
```

This first contract can call a function on the token contract that is only available to it.

```
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external onlyFirstContract {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }
```

I'm trying to test if I can call the mint function on behalf of the first contract using the delegatecall in foundry.

I tried passing the following data to delegatecall, this would execute in the context of the first contract:

abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether);
abi.encodeWithSignature("token.mintToken(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether);
abi.encodeWithSignature("testToken.mintToken(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether);

however I'm not able to access the function on the second contract.

Comment: You may need to clear what delegatecall do, it's `When contract A executes delegatecall to contract B, B's code is executed with contract A's storage, msg.sender and msg.value`
refer: https://solidity-by-example.org/delegatecall/
delegatecall doesn't modify storage data on your token contract, instead it will modify storage datas on your first contract which are the same storage slot with token contract.

About function data: this is right `abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether);`

Comment: I understand the delegatecall part but the problem is that I'm not able to access the mint function , because its impelementation is in the imported contract. So when I pass this call data abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether); the evm reverts because the function is not declared within the contract..

Comment: what I need is a syntax to access functions in this token:                                             
``` 
import {testToken} from "./testToken.sol";
testToken public token; 
``` 
something along the lines of : 

``` 
abi.encodeWithSignature("token.mintToken(address,uint256)", generatedAddress, 1 ether); 
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what syntax do you use to delegatecall?
This is mine:   
```
function delegate(address to, address receipt, uint256 amount) public  {
    (bool success, ) = to.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256,uint256)", receipt, amount));
  }
```
If you get error something like "low level...", it doesn't mean your mint function not found. It may came from this modifier `onlyFirstContract`. I don't have your code, but I guess you're checking msg.sender == firstContract. But when delegatecall, msg.sender doesn't change. it should be you sender wallet.